# Rising Pitch Siren Electronics Circuit Explanation

Tags: transistors, capacitor, audio, breadboard, basic

Can somebody **explain** me how in detail what is going in this circuit? I tried it and it was working but I cannot understand how this works.

[image]
http://startingelectronics.com/beginners/start-electronics-now/tut6-rising-pitch-siren/

Also how to know the polarity of a loudspeaker and does this polarity really matter in this or any circuit?

And what is the role of the non-polarized capacitor?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the circuit: -

[image]

See the notes I made on the circuit for explanation why you get a gradual rising pitch over several seconds.

To my knowledge loudspeakers only have polarity markings so they can be paralleled and pump sound in phase with each other correctly. For this circuit it won't matter but please do note that the circuit that drives the loudspeaker is not ideal in that there will always be a dc component of current flowing through the speaker.

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: Q1 & Q2 form an oscillator who's frequency is dependent on R2 & C2 time constant. The time constant of R2 & C2 is also dependent on the voltage across C1. As C1 charges, its voltage increases, and the frequency of the oscillator (and the tone heard from the speaker) increases in frequency. Correct me if I'm wrong, please, @Andy aka

Comment: FWIW - some speakers are less happy with DC bias in one direction than the other - ie they will 'bottom' quicker one way than other. Not usually a major issue.

Comment: @jwygralak67 oscillation does depend on R2 and C2 but also the current into the base - this can be thought of as a variable resistor that gets smaller as C1 charges up so oscillation depends on \$R_{INTO-THE-BASE}\$, R2 and C2. Remember the base-emitter is a diode so you'll get this variable base-resistance effect due to the diode slope changing with more bias.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - I didn't know that - maybe it's an antipodean thing LOL (does that term apply to NZ?)

Comment: @Andyaka It does depend on construction but if they are built symmetrically for audio then DC is going to offset the mean position so they poll at one end first. If not built with travel symmetry then one way will allow more AC travel with a given DC polarisation. | If you align the axis along the earth's magnetic lines the resultant offset will be opposite here in the antipodes than in lands where you don't stand on your heads, but you'd be hard pressed to measure the difference :-). Little known fact: The antipodes of Australia is the Bermuda Triangle - that possibly explains a lot :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thanks for that dude - Ill bear it in mind next time I fly the atlantic LOL

Comment: Is it really true to say that the time constant R2 C2 reduces? A simulation suggests that the period of oscillation is dominated by a part of the cycle where the voltage at the base of Q2 is below ground, so C2 is discharging through R2 alone. The change in pitch comes from the fact that this exponential discharge tends to the slowly-varying voltage across C1, so the threshold of 0.6V at which Q2 conducts occurs at a slowly-varying point in the exponential decay curve. It's not so much a varying time constant, then, as that one cycle takes a varying number of (fixed) time constants R2 C2.

Comment: its not true because R2 and C2 are fixed values but something changes and to my mind that can be attributed to the non linear impedance into the base. If you've done a sim pls publish as an answer. My analysis was off the cuff.

Comment: Can I have a more in depth solution because we have not yet started with circuit designing or any in-depth electronics stuff

Comment: @Ashish, from the perspective of an EE,  my answer should be enough. To construct an answer for a non EE would require pages of info going into the workings of bipolar transistors, exponential charging and probably even ohms law. How can anyone know your skill set in order to make the best answer most suitable for you?

Comment: Can you also tell me how the transistors are working

Comment: Read my previous comment please and don't assume I understand what knowledge you have on stuff. I gave an EE compatible answer but if you are a novice, this isn't a university or training facility.